# cannot find module ;aws-sdk'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have downloaded aws-sdk from AWS and copied the folder to nodejs installed directory at below Path:

```
c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\aws-sdk
```

we have network restriction at server level to install aws-sdk using command prompt so we cannot use 
`>npm install aws-sdk`

When I am trying to execute sample code, I am getting an error stating: cannot find module ;aws-sdk'

Please can anyone help? if any configuration is missing or missed when we manually copy 'aws-sdk' files to nodejs folder.

Note: I am trying this on Windows OS.

Comment: There was permission issue on windows server. Adding admin previledge solve the problem,